# Laravel group by not working

Tags: sql, laravel

I have table with attributes. Table has columns: `attr_id`, `value`.
I want group records by `attr_id` and prevent duplicates, because in table can be multiple `attr_id` with: 3,2,1 ids. I need to show list of this attributes grouped by attr_id.

How can I do this?

```
$attrs = Attribute::groupBy('attr_id')->get();
```

not working.

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.attributes.value' which is not functionally dependent on columns
```

Comment: From multiple `attr_id`s which id you want to show, as per newer version  this error is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
$attrs = Attribute::get()->groupBy('attr_id');
```

That will use groupBy() function from Laravel collections https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby

Else you are using "group by" incorrectly because you have to specify all the keys you want to be returned. You should read what group by does: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm